# MTKView displaying CIImage goes wrong when image changes size

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I'm using a fairly standard subclass of `MTKView` that displays a CIImage, for the purposes of rapidly updating using CIFilters. Code for the `draw()` function is below.

The problem I have is that only the portions of the view that are covered by the image, in this case `scaledImage` in the code below, are actually redrawn. This means that if the new image is smaller than the previous image, I can still see portions of the old image poking out from behind it.

Is there a way to clear the content of the drawable's texture when the size of the contained image changes, so that this does not happen?

```
override func draw() {
    guard let image = image,
        let targetTexture = currentDrawable?.texture,
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
        else { return }

    let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: drawableSize)

    let scaleX = drawableSize.width / image.extent.width
    let scaleY = drawableSize.height / image.extent.height
    let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)

    let width = image.extent.width * scale
    let height = image.extent.height * scale
    let originX = (bounds.width - width) / 2
    let originY = (bounds.height - height) / 2

    let scaledImage = image
        .transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
        .transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: originX, y: originY))

    ciContext.render(
        scaledImage,
        to: targetTexture,
        commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
        bounds: bounds,
        colorSpace: colorSpace
    )

    guard let drawable = currentDrawable else { return }
    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
    super.draw()
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `MTKView` just to apply filters to an image. You can just set filters on the layer of a `UIImageView`.

Comment: From the Apple documentation on CALayer: `This property is not supported on layers in iOS.`

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry.

Comment: No probs, thanks for the input anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

`MTKView` has `clearColor` property which you can use like so:

```
clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to use `CIImage`, you can just create one with `CIColor` like so:

```
CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1)).cropped(to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: drawableSize))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is tell the `ciContext` to clear the texture before you draw to it.
So before you do this,

```
ciContext.render(
        scaledImage,
        to: targetTexture,
        commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
        bounds: bounds,
        colorSpace: colorSpace)
```

clear the context by first.

```
let renderDestination = CIRenderDestination(
            width: Int(sizeToClear.width),
            height: Int(sizeToClear.height),
            pixelFormat: colorPixelFormat,
            commandBuffer: nil) { () -> MTLTexture in
            return drawable.texture
        }
do {
    try ciContext.startTask(toClear: renderDestination)
} catch {

}
```

For more info see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/2875450-starttask)

Answer (score 0):

I have the following solution which works, but I'm not very pleased with it as it feels hacky so please, somebody tell me a better way of doing it!

What I'm doing is tracking when the size of the image changes and setting a flag called `needsRefresh`. During the view's `draw()` function I then check to see if this flag is set and, if it is, I create a new CIImage from the view's `clearColor` that's the same size as the drawable and render this before continuing to the image I actually want to render.

This seems really inefficient, so better solutions are welcome!

Here's the additional drawing code:

```
    if needsRefresh {
        let color = UIColor(mtkColor: clearColor)
        let clearImage = CIImage(cgImage: UIImage.withColor(color, size: bounds.size)!.cgImage!)
        ciContext.render(
            clearImage,
            to: targetTexture,
            commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
            bounds: bounds,
            colorSpace: colorSpace
        )
        needsRefresh = false
    }
```

Here's the `UIColor` extension for converting the clear color:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(mtkColor: MTLClearColor) {
        let red = CGFloat(mtkColor.red)
        let green = CGFloat(mtkColor.green)
        let blue = CGFloat(mtkColor.blue)
        let alpha = CGFloat(mtkColor.alpha)
        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

And finally, a small extension for creating CIImages from a given background colour:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func withColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }   
}
```

Comment: You could do something similar except use a render command encoder that targets the drawable's texture with load action `.clear`, `clearColor` the same as the view's, and store action `.store`. You don't have to encode any commands to it. Just create it and then end encoding on it. That will clear the drawable's texture.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm moving towards using pure Metal for speed, rather than an uncomfortable hodgepodge of CIFilter and Metal. I've replacing my weird subclass with a plain MTKView and a rendering delegate and am using encoders to work directly on textures. Should be much better, although it means I'll have to convert back from textures to a suitable file output.